# Am I supposed to build a typescript npm module before deployment?

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to figure out how to use a Typescript package I have made in a JavaScript application. The main wall I'm running into is that I'm not sure if I'm supposed to build the typescript package first and then use npm to locally import it, or if there is an automatic build process npm will run when installing the package that I can take advantage of. Any help in this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to build before deployment, and publish `.js` and `.d.ts` files with `npm`.

Building at install time can fail, which will be harder to debug for you compared with debugging build failures at publish time. You can look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8186)  for an example how a build can go wrong for unknown reasons.